# Server.TransferRequest on Visual Studio Test Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I can't find any info on this... I keep getting some error saying I need IIS integrated mode. Does `Server.TransferRequest` not work on visual studio?

My start options say "Use Default Server".

Here is how it is being used:

```
Server.TransferRequest("RegisterSuccess.aspx?email="+ tbEmail.Text);
```

Comment: I said im using the Visual Studio test server.

Comment: In what context are you using `Server.TransferRequest`? Are you writing an ad-on? Is this your own .net application that you're writing?

Comment: What does your web project start options look like?  Sounds like you are pointing to IIS.

Comment: That is not always adequate that is way I don't use that. I had some hinderances with it and got rid of it quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"The new `TransferRequest` method  performs a complete request by using an `IIS 7` worker thread. This means that the page request will go through the complete `ASP.NET` pipeline, giving every module a chance of interacting with the request."*

See more [ASP.NET: Using Server.TransferRequest](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/asp-net/79c73563-408a-493e-a369-d4b380bce549/aspnet-using-servertransferrequest.aspx)

*"(ASP) features introduced with Internet Information Services `(IIS) version 5.0` is a transfer method for the ASP built-in Server object."*

See more [How to Use the Server.Transfer Method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/219294)

Comment: Thanks, `Transfer` works just as fine for my case. I think `TransferRequest` is more useful in cases when you want to create a new request completely.

Answer (score 3):

Correct.  This will not work with the VS Dev Server.  Here are details from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx). The VS Dev Server does not very closely match IIS 7 and it doesn't run in integrated mode so you're better off not using it if that's what your production environment is.  And TransferRequest requires Integrated mode.