# IIS integrated pipeline mode with `Server.TransferRequest( "Form2.aspx" );`

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2012, integrated-pipeline-mode

I have a line of `C#` code like this:

```
Server.TransferRequest( "Form2.aspx" );
```

I run it on IIS 7 without a problem, but when I run my code with Visual Studio 2012 (with its internal server, for debugging or something like that) I get an exception:

```
This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.
```

What should I do?

Comment: I use IISExpress instead of VS internal server, so I don't have this problem now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server.TransferRequest on Visual Studio Test Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337792/server-transferrequest-on-visual-studio-test-server)